# Detect unsaved data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winform with a menustrip New, Open, Save and somethings like: Textbox
How can I detect unsaved data in textbox and popup a window to ask user to save their data  when closing the program?
I respect all your advices.

Comment: Use a flag, and reset when using textbox, textchanged event. Then the flag can be used to detect whether user edit anything

Answer (score 1):

you need to register all textbox-change event to know textbox text changed or not

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    var c = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox));
    foreach (TextBox item in c)
        item.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged);
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //set textbox tag = true to check whether text changed or not
        ((TextBox)sender).Tag=true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type)
    {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

        return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
                                  .Concat(controls)
                                  .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
    }

    // now you can get changed checkbox 
    List<TextBox> getchangedtextbox(){
    var c = GetAll(this,typeof(TextBox));
        // not get list of changed checkbox witch have null value in TAG
       return c.Select(a=>a.Tag!=null);
    }
```

Comment: I so agree with your solution, and I'm facing with unsaved List<string>, can you help?

Comment: i think this statement 'return c.Select(a=>a.Tag!=null);' will be 'return c.Select(a=>a.Tag!=null).ToList();'

Comment: Could I ask you by email?

Comment: you're asking me? @TuyenNguyen

Comment: @Zohaib Aslam: yes sir

Answer (score 0):

define a boolean variable named isDataChanged and set it to false. on keypressed event of textbox set this variable to true. when user close the program, check if this variable is true. if it is true show a message and when user saves the data set it back to false otherwise exit the program :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could user is a define a `boolean` variable such as `bDirty`.

Initially declare this variable as `FALSE`, but set it true in your `_TextChanged` event - for example `myTextBox_TextChanged` (so `bDirty` will be now `TRUE` if the textBox was edited)

On close / exit then check `bDirty` and show a MessageBox if `bDirty` is `TRUE` as follows:

```
 if (bDirty) 
 {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes?", "Confirmation", messageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
            //... Do something
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
            //...Do something esle
        else
            //...Do something else - go wild! 
 }
```

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

but when you have multiple input fields then triggering on_click events against each inputs is difficult, I modify above logic as below:

Declare global variable

```
Boolean isDataChanged = false;
```

Now, create form/group leave event, by default it is false so it will generate the message .. and will work whenever the form/group lost focus :-)

```
private void grp_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isDataChanged == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("data is not saved, either saved or cancel");
    }
}
```

On Save and Cancel button, set the boolean to true

```
isDataChanged = true;

private void bttn_SAVE(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  isDataChanged = true;
    
  // call your function to save_data
    
}


private void bttn_Cancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  isDataChanged = false;
    
  // call your function to show_data
    
}
```

this logic works for me, hit like if this logic worked for you too (Y)